# Typing an assoc function to properly infer new type

Tags: typescript

I have setup an `assoc` function (to associate a new key with a new value on an object):

```js
export const assoc = <T, U, K extends PropertyKey>(
    newKey: PropertyKey,
    newValue: U,
    o: T,
) => ({
        ...o,
        [newKey]: newValue,
    });
```

But the type I get out is:

```js
T & {
    [x: string]: U;
}
```

I've tried manually specifying the output type to be:

```js
{ [key: K]: U }
```

But the key must be a string or a number, fair enough.

I've also tried the following:

```js
export const assoc = <K1 extends PropertyKey, K2 extends PropertyKey, T, U extends Record<K1, T>, V>(
    newKey: K2,
    newValue: V,
    o: U,
): U & Record<K2, V> => ({
        ...o,
        [newKey]: newValue,
    });
```

But this gives me the error:

> Type 'U & { [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to type 'U &
>   Record'.   Type 'U & { [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'Record'

I'm stuck as to the proper way to type this; really I just want the compiler to know that it'll have the type of the input object, only extended with the new key/value pair. Any thoughts?

Comment: Afraid the only solution is a type assertion `{ [newKey]: newValue }` will infer an index signature if `newKey` is a generic type parameter not `Record<K2, V>`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir many thanks - that's good to know, I may well go with the type assertion in that case